# 2009 iMac works in safe mode, but not normally

Tags: imac, startup, hardware, safe-mode

I have a 2009 model 27" iMac (core i7) running El Capitan. When booted into normal mode, it is extremely slow to the point of being unresponsive, and the GUI has problems (pictures to follow). 
However, when booted into safe mode, it functions normally (for a 2009 computer).

Furthermore, I could not boot from an external drive, I tried both Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) and OS X (El Capitan and Yosemite) drives, both of which could boot my MBA just fine.

I'm not sure if these two issues are related. The machine has had hardware problems in the past (power supply & hard drive failures) both of which were repaired at "Apple Certified Technicians", but not actual Apple stores.

Comment: Safe Mode is the bare OS without any extra apps being loaded.  So, the question is, what do you have automatically starting?

Comment: I'm not sure. The problems begin even before you login though, so I don't think it's connected to my login items. How do I check what OS X loads on boot?